# Change entity bundle on update?

Tags: 7, migrations

Is it safe to change the entity bundle (e.g. node type or commerce product type) when updating an entity with Migrate API?

Specific use case:

The site already contains plenty of commerce_product entities with `$product->type === 'product'`, that were imported with something other than Migrate API.

I now want to re-import these entities with Migrate API, updating the existing entities.
[Custom MigrateMap to sync by field or property, e.g. SKU](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/206937/custom-migratemap-to-sync-by-field-or-property-e-g-sku)

The product type should be changed to something else by the update, let's say `$product->type === 'othertype'`.

Some of the fields are the same in both bundles. Other fields only exist in one of the bundles. Data from obsolete fields should be discarded / deleted. This includes images from an image field.

---

So, I wonder if all of this will happen painlessly, or if I need to do something special to make it work.

I will try this anyway and see what happens, but I think it is useful to have this documented here on stackexchange.

Comment: I know there are modules like site:drupal.org/project node convert and https://www.drupal.org/project/bundleswitcher, so changing a bundle is technically possible.

Comment: Oops. I mean this of course. https://www.drupal.org/project/node_convert

Comment: @kiamlaluno Are you sure the title change does not obscure the intent of the question, if someone is looking at a list of questions? I realize the migrate context might be irrelevant for the solution. But it is relevant for people looking specifically for the problem within a migrate context.

Comment: We have tags for that purpose; there is no need to repeat them in the title, in the same way there is no need to put _Drupal_ in the title.

Comment: If you look at a list of related questions in the sidebar, you don't see the tags. But you do know it is drupal.stackexchange. Also the tag "migration" does not necessarily mean the specific "Migrate API" module, does it? I don't want to discuss this forever. If I cannot convince you I will leave the name change :)

Comment: That is the only place where you don't see the tags; in the other places where questions are listed, you see them. That is not an argument, though. You cannot put everything in the title, or make a title clear in every context. Shall we put _Drupal_ in the title for those people who find our questions from Google? You don't need to convince me: Stack Exchange already decided to avoid tags in titles.

Comment: The visible site name is "Drupal answers". So no, Drupal does not need to be in any title.

Comment: But the site name is not visible to the people who see the links to the question on Google. The point is that you cannot make the title helpful for every context where the title is used. We make them clear in the context of this site, where 99% of times, the title and tags are visible.

Comment: The title on Google is "7 - Change entity bundle on update? - Drupal Answers". But this discussion already happened on http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61059/166835 "I think it is fine to duplicate the tags in the title, but only when they can be worked into the titles organically and conversationally." (Jeff Atwood) And on meta.drupal.stackexchange [here](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/284/is-it-really-necessary-to-remove-a-term-from-the-question-title-and-replace-it-w/286) and [here](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/838/are-tags-allowed-in-questions-titles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems dangerous to me - a node's bundle is fundamental to its identity, and has repercussions well beyond the node's data itself. You're on Drupal 7, presumably? Simple way to test would be a script like:

```
$node = node_load(5);
$node->type = 'other_type';
node_save($node);
```

If it breaks there, it'll break with migration too. And if it works there, it should work with migration.

Comment: Well, the existence of https://www.drupal.org/project/node_convert suggests that it is generally possible. But maybe not trivial. I will try and report how it works. I imagine that it will work if the validation of the new type passes. But there could be broken leftovers.

Comment: And I should mention that node_convert has worked reliably for me in past projects.

Comment: So far in this new project, the product type converting seems ok so far. I will report if there are problems. Also see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/208040/how-to-make-entity-revisions-remember-the-old-bundle-if-it-is-changed