# How to make entity revisions remember the old bundle, if it is changed?

Tags: 7, entities

There are some tools in Drupal that allow you to change the bundle of an entity (e.g. the node type):

- The [Node Convert](//drupal.org/project/node_convert) module
- The migrate module, if you update an entity and change the bundle.
- Any custom programmatical bundle change, see [Change entity bundle on update?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/206947/change-entity-bundle-on-update/206987#206987)

(In my case it is about commerce_product entities where the bundle changes from "product" to something else)

Entity revisions, if enabled, can remember all the field data from the old entity, even if these fields do not exist in the newly assigned bundle.

However, when loading the old revision with e.g. `entity_load()`, it has the new bundle, not the old one. And `field_attach_load()` only loads field data for fields of the new bundle.

A place to look is `DrupalDefaultEntityController::load()`. This queries the database for the entity / revision, and then calls `$this->attachLoad()` to add the field data. Then e.g. `CommerceProductEntityController::attachLoad()` calls the parent `DrupalDefaultEntityController::attachLoad()`, which calls `field_attach_load_revision()`, which calls `field_attach_load()`, which determines the entity bundle and loads the field instances for the determined bundle. The bundle is already on the entity since it was loaded from the database.

It seems the main problem is that (most or all of) the revision tables do not have a column for the bundle. I assume this could be changed with `hook_schema_alter()` to add a `type` column to `commerce_product_revision` (or `node_revision`). But will this cause other problems?

Has anyone tried this so far, or knows an existing solution? Anything I can think of right now seems hackish and fragile.

Comment: Would it be a choice if you use a field to store the bundle type?

Comment: @JimmyKo If this solves the problem, why not. But does it?

Comment: Also I could "cheat" and just say that revisions before a certain date are the old bundle, and revisions past that date are the new bundle. But this still means I need to somehow tell the entity controller. Maybe just register my own overridden controller for commerce products?

Comment: Adding a new field may cause less problem because I suspect if core and modules assume the structure of revision table is same as the entity one. But I just come up an idea. Maybe you can add the bundle column on both entity and revision table. IMPO, it won't cause too much problem because most module only handle the entity table and ignore the revision one.

Comment: So I store the bundle in a field. Then what? Drupal still thinks that it is the other bundle.